# Can I Install Window 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning

I bought my laptop some time ago (**HP Pavilion g6**) and it came pre-installed with Windows 8. There was a problem with my OS (I couldn't reset or refresh) so I just installed **Ubuntu 13**. My only OS currently is Ubuntu and **I don't have the recovery partition** or anything like that, simply one Ubuntu partition. I'd like to install Windows 8, seeing how 8.1 is out and there are good reviews about it. Can I install Windows on my Laptop without

**a)** Having to buy a Windows 8 CD (My laptop didn't come with it and there is no cd key anywhere on my laptop.

**b)** Without losing my Ubuntu files. I'd like to dual boot.

In my Bios it says the factory installed OS is Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot press F11 directly after powering up the unit, you are correct that you do not have the recovery partition.

The Win 8 key is encrypted into the system BIOS/UEFI storage area.  You cannot use any install image though to decrypt this.  There are 2 options to get Windows loaded on the machine with the serial that came with it is to contact HP and have them send you the corresponding recovery disks for the specific laptop model.  If your laptop is still under warranty, you can order the recovery image from HP for like $10 to cover shipping.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07143&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N103

The other option is try to find the recovery image on the internet somewhere and download it there and be sure to have the right checksum before install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to find the correct install media from Microsoft or HP.

Windows 8 PC's come with the license key embedded in the BIOS.

Although this makes things easy in your case, in general that is pretty disastrous since the license is never transferable. It is tied to the PC.

Dual booting is slightly more complex. The easiest way is to install Windows first and then Ubuntu.

In your case, you need to use Linux disk tools from a live CD to defrag the data and make the data partition smaller. Make sure that, when you reduce the partition size, you keep the partition at the end of the disk not the start. The reason for this is that Windows typically likes to occupy the first physical active partition. Next create a new partition for Windows, mark the Linux partition as hidden and install Windows. Then you would need to sort out the dual boot. Re-enable the Linux partition first.

Not sure what is next in that instance as I've not done it.

Personally, I'd move my data to a new small partition, create both a Windows and Linux boot partition, install Windows then install Ubuntu again.

UPDATE:
To legally obtain Windows 8 media, there are a number of ways. [This link from Microsoft](http://pcsupport.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=pcsupport&cdn=compute&tm=122&f=00&su=p284.13.342.ip_p504.6.342.ip_&tt=65&bt=4&bts=45&zu=http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) may work, worth trying. Otherwise, obtain replacement media from the PC manufacturer or get the media via MSDN or similar business partner connection. Finally, it may be possible to recreate the [install media from a friends PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media).

Comment: Can I install Windows 8.1 or can I only install Windows 8. Also can you provide me with the correct media link?

Comment: See my update for ideas. You should be able to install 8.1 but this *is* Microsoft we are talking about and I haven't tried all the options.

Comment: In regards to the new link, I don't already have Windows (thought I have Win 7 on a VM) and I don't have my Key, unless I can get it from my Bios?

Comment: The key is built in to the BIOS and the installation *should* recognise it. Only Enterprise versions of W8 allow entry of a key AFIK now.

Comment: So I should download the iso and burn it on a USB and then install it?

Comment: You will need to have a play I'm afraid. I've not needed to do something like this as yet. Go ahead and try - see if it works. Feel free to put in your own answer if you get it working, its fine.